# Combining Text_Grob with ggplot via grid_arrange - delete Text_grob-Margins

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have been trying to merge a TextGrob with a ggplot for some time. Unfortunately, the TextGrob always creates a certain distance to the plot, which I do not want.

The whole thing becomes a bit clearer when looking at the current result:

[image: Current output]

The goal is to have the "Lennart" directly on the plot, as a kind of artificial axis label.

The current code looks like this: (I have adjusted the formatting somewhat, but the essentials should be recognisable)

```
png("PNGZwischenspeicher2.png", bg = "transparent", width = 2500, height = 1000)
p <- ggplot(DBE3, aes(x = reorder(emoji, n), y = n,reorder(emoji,-n)))+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0, "pt"))+
  geom_col(alpha = 0.2, width = 0.2)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("transparent", "transparent", "transparent"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.00, .5)))
print(p)
dev.off()
img2 <- readPNG("PNGZwischenspeicher2.png")
PE2 <- rasterGrob(img2)

Header2 <- textGrob("Lennart", rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface = 'plain'))
grid.arrange(Header2, PE2, nrow = 1)
```

Don't ask why it is necessary to edit the plot via the png-workaround, the current script doesn't allow it otherwise :D

If anyone knows a way to remove the space between the text_grob and the plot (or png), I would be very grateful.
My approach would be to adjust the size of the text_grob, but unfortunately I haven't found a working way to do this yet.

Thank you very much and have a nice evening!

---

Data needed for recreation:

```
dput(DBE3)
structure(list(author = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lennart", 
"Toni Janina", "Toni"), class = "factor"), emoji = c("<U+0001F607>", 
"<U+0001F64F>", "<U+0001F605>"), n = c(90L, 47L, 30L), name = c("smiling face with halo", 
"folded hands", "grinning face with sweat"), hex_runes = c("1F607", 
"1F64F", "1F605"), hex_runes1 = c("1F607", "1F64F", "1F605"), 
    emoji_url = c("https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f607.png", 
    "https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f64f.png", "https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f605.png"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(author = structure(1L, .Label = c("Lennart", 
"Toni Janina", "Toni"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You could adjust the widths, e.g. `grid.arrange(Header2, PE2, nrow = 1, widths = c(1, 19))`

Comment: There is a new package {gggrid} (https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gggrid/gggrid.html) that lets you add a grob directly to a ggplot. 
You could also use `geom_grob()` from my package {ggpp}, which allows positioning the grob based on x and y aesthetics, or `geom_grob_npc()` which supports npc coordinates.
Both packages are in CRAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler example that shows how to add a textGrob to a ggplot with {ggpp} (or {ggpmisc}). This could be also done with `geom_text()` but I guess you have something more complicated as the actual problem. This code can be used with any grob including bitmaps.

```r
library(ggpp)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate
library(grid)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "grob", x = 5, y = 40, 
           label = textGrob("Lennart", rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface = 'plain')))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>